# How to declare the return of a function as the default parameter to another function without calling the first function?

Tags: python

It seems a litle confuse, but my task is the following:

I have a personalyzed python module named functions, where I declare many tasks that are often used in my project. One of these functions is `read_servers_list()`, this gets a list of servers that an action will be done in. Another function is called `automation(command, servers, mixed = False, logs = False, csv = False)`  which is responsible for a repetitive task in the servers list defined by the user. Most times, the servers in `automation()` are get by the read_servers_list () functions, so i set it as the default value `automation(servers -read_servers_list ())`. But I got a problem, when I import the function module into another module (`import functions`), the `read_servers_list()` is executed twice, once during the import action and another when I use the `functions.automation()`.

Could someone help me, I wish to import the functions and execute the `read_servers_list()`  only when it is called.

Comment: In your ``functions.py`` use ``if __name__ == "__main__":``, This will avoid calling your function ``read_servers_list()`` during the import.

(**refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do**)

Comment: I tried that, but a got an eror "functions has no attribute automation"

Comment: "read_servers_list() is executed twice, once during the import action and another when I use the functions.automation()." that shouldn't be happening. Can you elaborate more on exactly what you are seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Just have the default as `None`, then check for that in the function:

```
def automation(command, servers=None, mixed=False, logs=False, csv=False):
    if servers is None:
        servers = read_servers_list()
    . . .
```

The default arguments get evaluated regardless of whether or not they're used. If you want to delay them being called until they're actually needed, run them in the function instead.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated your scenario below:

1. My `functions.py`:

```
def read_servers_list():
    return ["server1", "server2", "server3"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(read_servers_list())
```

2. My `main_code.py`

```
import functions

print(functions.read_servers_list())
```

When I use `if __name__ == "__main__"`, the code block below it will be executed only when the called function is itself. This will avoid calling the main part of your import functions.